# LMI variable is null after LMI resolution

Tags: matlab

The resolution of the lmi gives 0 value for two variables (it should be between 0 and 1)

The LMI is for fault tolerant control systems

the program is as follows:

```
while true
    setlmis([])
    P_1 = lmivar(1,[2*n,1]);
    P_2 = lmivar(1,[2*n,1]);

    [G_1, l, sG_1] = lmivar(1,[n,1]);
    [G_2, l, sG_2] = lmivar(1,[n,1]);

    [L_1, l, sL_1] = lmivar(2,[n,m]);
    [L_2, l, sL_2] = lmivar(2,[n,m]);

    [k_1, l, sk_1] = lmivar(2,[m,n]);
    [k_2, l, sk_2] = lmivar(2,[m,n]);

    [K_1, l, slk] = lmivar(3,[sG_1,sL_1,zeros(n),[0;0];
                sk_1, 0, [0 0], 0;
                zeros(n), [0;0], sG_1, sL_1;
                [0 0], 0 sk_1, 0]);

    K_2 = lmivar(3,[sG_2,sL_2,zeros(n),[0;0];
                sk_2, 0, [0 0], 0;
                zeros(n), [0;0], sG_2, sL_2;
                [0 0], 0 sk_2, 0]);

    V_1 = lmivar(1,[1,0]);
    V_2 = lmivar(1,[1,0]);

    Q = [zeros(n) [0;0] zeros(n) [0;0]; -eye(n) [0;0] zeros(n) [0;0]];

    counter = 1;
    i = 1;
    j = 1;
    while counter <= 4
        if i ==1 && j ==1
            P_i = P_1;
            P_j = P_1;
            Vi = V_1;
            Ki = K_1;
            Ai = [A1 zeros(n) ; A1 zeros(n)];
            Bi = [zeros(n) [0;0] zeros(n) B1; zeros(n) [0;0] -eye(n) B1];
            C_Ci = [zeros(n) eye(n); [0 0] [0 0]; eye(n) -eye(n); C1 [0 0]];
            Ci = [[0 0] C1];
            Di = [N1 M1];
            Ei =[E1 F1; E1 F1];
            Ri = [[0 ; 0] [0 ; 0] ; N1 M1; [0 ; 0] [0 ; 0]; 0 0];

        elseif i ==1 && j ==2
            P_i = P_1;
            P_j = P_2;
            Vi = V_1;
            Ki = K_1;
            Ai = [A1 zeros(n) ; A1 zeros(n)];
            Bi = [zeros(n) [0;0] zeros(n) B1; zeros(n) [0;0] -eye(n) B1];
            C_Ci = [zeros(n) eye(n); [0 0] [0 0]; eye(n) -eye(n); C1 [0 0]];
            Ci = [[0 0] C1];
            Di = [N1 M1];
            Ei =[E1 F1; E1 F1];
            Ri = [[0 ; 0] [0 ; 0] ; N1 M1; [0 ; 0] [0 ; 0]; 0 0];
        elseif i ==2 && j ==1
            P_i = P_2;
            P_j = P_1;
            Vi = V_2;
            Ki = K_2;
            Ai = [A2 zeros(n) ; A2 zeros(n)];
            Bi = [zeros(n) [0;0] zeros(n) B2; zeros(n) [0;0] -eye(n) B2];
            C_Ci = [zeros(n) eye(n); [0 0] [0 0]; eye(n) -eye(n); C2 [0 0]];
            Ci = [[0 0] C2];
            Di = [N2 M2];
            Ei =[E2 F2; E2 F2];
            Ri = [[0 ; 0] [0 ; 0] ; N2 M2; [0 ; 0] [0 ; 0]; 0 0];
        elseif i ==2 && j ==2
            P_i = P_2;
            P_j = P_2;
            Vi = V_2;
            Ki = K_2;
            Ai = [A2 zeros(n) ; A2 zeros(n)];
            Bi = [zeros(n) [0;0] zeros(n) B2; zeros(n) [0;0] -eye(n) B2];
            C_Ci = [zeros(n) eye(n); [0 0] [0 0]; eye(n) -eye(n); C2 [0 0]];
            Ci = [[0 0] C2];
            Di = [N2 M2];
            Ei =[E2 F2; E2 F2];
            Ri = [[0 ; 0] [0 ; 0] ; N2 M2; [0 ; 0] [0 ; 0]; 0 0];
        end

            lmiterm([counter,1,1,P_j],Ai',Ai)
            lmiterm([counter,1,1,P_i],-1,1)
            lmiterm([counter,1,1,P_j],-epsilon*Ai'*Bi*Bi',Ai)
            lmiterm([counter,1,1,P_j],-epsilon*Ai',Bi*Bi'*Ai)
            lmiterm([counter,1,1,0],epsilon*epsilon*Ai'*Bi*Bi'*Ai)

            lmiterm([counter,3,1,Vi],1,Ci)

            lmiterm([counter,4,1,0],Ai)
            lmiterm([counter,4,1,Ki],Bi,C_Ci)

            lmiterm([counter,5,1,P_j],Bi',Ai)
            lmiterm([counter,5,1,Ki],1,C_Ci)

            lmiterm([counter,6,1,Ki],epsilon*Bi,C_Ci)

            lmiterm([counter,2,2,0],-current_gama*current_gama*eye(n))

            lmiterm([counter,3,2,Vi],1,Di)

            lmiterm([counter,4,2,0],Ei)
            lmiterm([counter,4,2,Ki],Q,Ri)

            lmiterm([counter,3,3,0],-1)

            lmiterm([counter,4,4,0],-2*eye(2*n))
            lmiterm([counter,4,4,P_j],1,1)

            lmiterm([counter,5,5,0],-eye(2*n+2*m))

            lmiterm([counter,6,6,P_j],1,1)
            lmiterm([counter,6,6,0],-2*epsilon*eye(2*n))

            counter = counter + 1;

            if i == 1 && j ==1
                i = 2;
                j = 1;
            elseif i == 2 && j == 1
                i = 1;
                j = 2;
            elseif i == 1 && j == 2
                i = 2;
                j = 2;
            end
    end

    lmiterm([-5,1,1,P_1],1,1)
    lmiterm([-6,1,1,P_2],1,1)

    mLMI = getlmis;
    [t, x] = feasp(mLMI);

    if  current_gama <= 0
        break;
    end

    if t < 0
        V1 = dec2mat(mLMI, x, V_1)
        V2 = dec2mat(mLMI, x, V_2)
        P1 = dec2mat(mLMI, x, P_1)
        P2 = dec2mat(mLMI, x, P_2)
        K1 = dec2mat(mLMI, x, K_1)
        K2 = dec2mat(mLMI, x, K_2)
        G1 = K1(1:n, 1:n)
        G2 = K2(1:n, 1:n)
        L1 = K1(1:n, n+1)
        L2 = K2(1:n, 1+n)
        k1 = K1(n+1, 1:n)
        k2 = K2(n+1, 1:n)

        last_gama = current_gama;

        current_gama = current_gama - gama_step;
        continue;
    else
        current_gama = current_gama - gama_step;
        continue;
    end
end
```

Other variables are none 0, but V1 and V2 are scalars that are equal to zero.
The matrices A1,A2,B1,B2,C1,C2,D1,D2E1,E2,F1,F2,M1,M2,N1,N2 are declared as global in a script
There values aras follows:

```
A1 = [.2 -.1; 0 .4];
B1 = [.1 ; .3];
C1 = [.1 0];
E1 = [.2 ; .1];
F1 = [.13 ; .16];
N1 = 1.1;
M1 = 1.4;
A2 = [.4 .1; .1 .3];
B2 = [.3 ; .2];
C2 = [0 .1];
E2 = [.2 ; .3];
F2 = [.15 ; .12];
N2 = 1.2;
M2 = 1.5;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that V1 and V2 are positive definite, so the trick as suggested by one of my collegus is to add an LMI to specify that as folows :

```
lmiterm([-7,1,1,V1],1,1)
lmiterm([-8,1,1,V2],1,1)
```

By doing this V1 and V2 will not be null!